# MVC3 resize image without losing quality?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

Hello everybody I would like to ask how can I resize an image without losing quality?

Here is my controller method

```
var fileName = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM.dd.yyyy HH.mm.ss") + Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
            var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/uploads/"), fileName);
            file.SaveAs(path);
            System.Drawing.Image img = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(Server.MapPath("~/uploads/") + fileName);
            System.Drawing.Image thumb = img.GetThumbnailImage(97, 114, null, IntPtr.Zero);
            img.Dispose();
            thumb.Save(Server.MapPath("~/uploads/") + fileName);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some really good image resizing libraries out there - I would use one of those. I'm using [ImageResizing](http://imageresizing.net/) on one of my projects and the results have been pretty good. Bertrand LeRoy has done some [benchmarking](http://weblogs.asp.net/bleroy/archive/2011/10/22/state-of-net-image-resizing-how-does-imageresizer-do.aspx) of some of the main libraries, which you might find useful.

Comment: How can I save an image with using imageresizer  could you give an example ?

Comment: It's pretty trivial really - there's a static singleton that you access, which takes and input and target stream/file: `ImageBuilder.Current.Build(sourceFile, targetFile, new ResizeSettings(width, height, FitMode.Crop, null));` - you can pass it either a stream or a filename. Intellisense should tell you all the options available